# Ruby on rails, what are the keys inside parameter object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to ask what are the list of keys in the `params` object. Code from rails guide:

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
```

Comment: `puts params.keys.inspect`.

Comment: params key differ from model to model. The keys are based on your Model columns and the passed params in the url. You can inspect using puts params.inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from keys like `action`, `controller` and `authenticity_token`, the `keys` in most `params` object differ from application to application. The best way to see what is in your params is to `inspect` it.

In the code you posted above, for example, you could use [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug)  or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to pause execution (similar to setting a breakpoint).

Though my personal preference is `pry`, let's take an example with `byebug` since it ships by default with rails.

```
def destroy
    byebug
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Once you've added this, hit the `destroy` route from the view, then go back to your console. You should see execution paused at that point.

You can then access `params` or any other variable already defined. Typing `params` followed by the enter key will show you everything in the params object.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `debug(params)`. That will give you a nicely formatted view of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to print in browser and see all params what passed.

```
render plain: params
```

Answer (score 0):

You can best understand this with the help of an action which involves a form(`create` or `update`). Try this in your `create` action.

```
def create
  render text: params
end
```

This will display all the key-value pairs in the `params` including keys like `authenticity_token`, `controller`, `action`, `commit` and form values.

If you're only interested in the form values, try

```
def create
  render text: params[:article]
end
```

Hope this helps!